# Tie instead of a Rest in Keyboard Staff notation

Tags: notation, keyboard, rests, sustain, ties

I am learning keyboard notation. I want to know why a tie is used across bar lines. Why can't they use a rest in bar 2?

[image: Two bars of keyboard staff notation. The upper staff has a chord filling both bars, represented as tied semibreves]

Comment: Why do you assume, that this would be same?

Answer (score 6):

The tie suggests to play and hold the Dm chord for 8 beats.  If there was a rest in the second bar, then the chord would only be held for 4 beats.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, but how do I hold it for 8 counts as the instrument suggested in the notation is Electric Piano. It will die down after 4 counts?Do I use a sustained pedal?

Comment: @roopakn Just hold it down for 8 beats. It will sound softer and softer but should never fade out completely. Sustain pedal is used to keep the notes sounding after you have let the keys go, but that is not necessary here because your right hand doesn't need to do anything else.

Comment: From a percussion point of view, it affects more on how you think of the sound rather than what the common listener would hear. Ultimately, this will affect how you feel the music and could affect your sound in some way. It affects your touch on the instrument.